# Are leaf weights in XGBoost equivalent to output values?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I need to explain both XGBoost and GBM in the same text and I want to keep the notation consistent. Friedman (2002) uses $\gamma$ to denote output values for leaves in GBM. Chen and Guestrin (2016) use $w$ to denote what they refer to as "leaf weights". As far as I understand the text correctly, that's just a synonym for output values, meaning I should use the same symbol for $\gamma$ and $w$. Am I correct, or did I misunderstand something?

Friedman (2002): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222573328_Stochastic_Gradient_Boosting

Chen and Guestrin (2016): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf

Comment: You also have to watch out for the fact that xgboost has "min_child_weight", where weight means yet another thing, the hessian.  That terminology might be traceable back to adaboost and the Friedman 'Additive Logistic Regression' that connects adaboost to gradient boosting, but I haven't totally pieced it together yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.

And that's too short for an answer, so notice in the xgboost paper, section 2.1 they initially refer to $w_i$ as *scores*, and

> calculate the final prediction by summing up the score in the corresponding leaves (given by $w$).

They first refer to them as "leaf weights" in section 2.2.